# Relocate eclipse.ini

Tags: macos, eclipse-rcp

Is there a way to build an RCP application an relocate the eclipse.ini in a different location from where the eclipse.exe is located?

The Eclipse Product wizard only provides a "Root directory" where all files are exported to.  It seems eclipse.exe has something built into it to look in the same directory for the ini parameters.

Comment: Why do you want it somewhere else?

Comment: I want to be able to edit the ini file, but leave all files in the root directory read-only.

Answer (score 4):

You can override where Eclipse looks for the `eclipse.ini` using the `--launcher.ini` command line argument to eclipse.

So if you do:

```
/path/to/eclipse -data /path/to/workspace
```

then it will use `/path/to/eclipse.ini` (on linux/win) and `/path/Eclipse/eclipse.ini` (on osx), if you want it to read a different file, do this:

```
/path/to/eclipse --launcher.ini /anotherpath/to/eclipse.ini -data /path/to/workspace
```

will cause eclipse to read `/anotherpath/to/eclipse.ini` instead of the default.

See [Eclipse Help on the launcher command line arguments](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html?cp=2_1_5_0).